# UI : Recommended books for good UI with a lot of forms, tables?

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, user-controls, webforms, user-experience

Im onto building a web application with lots of forms, and probably lots of editable, inputable, fancy tabular data.

Putting the technology used aside, im quite confused about how to layout the application. I've seen some using menu on the left, or the top of the page.

Or some use toolbar that contains the same CRUD buttons for every transaction forms.

Or some would use normal buttons inside that form inside the associated form panel.

Some would rather use lots input forms instead of using inputable grid, and they could next / prev the transaction forms just like flipping real papers.

Some would choose grid, and would have several types of grid that could ease the user a lot, like providing previous searches, or the user can even save the search criterias, etc.

I think i just want all these proven and good practices of designing a userfriendly interface in a book.

Does these kinds of books exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reco Designing Interfaces by Tidwell - it's an encylopedia.

Comment: whoa is it the complete book itself ?

Answer (score 1):

[Don't make me think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107) is a good place to start, when it comes to designing user friendly UI.

Comment: most UI books won't tell you how to design better forms, they will show you intuitive, visual alternatives ( eg. a row of baby heads to click on rather than entering the number of children in a box )